# atof() for float instead of double

Tags: c, ansi-c, atof

`atof()` returns a double, which results in a warning when I assign it to a float-value (and yes, I definitively have to use float).

So my question: is there a `atof()`-variant available which returns a plain float? Or do I have to solve this by a cast - which would be a pity because it wastes resources for creating a double which will be thrown away immediately.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. If you assign the result to a variable it doesn't matter if you cast it or not, no more memory will be used and the compiler might have some nice optimized function that will make it all negligible. Don't do premature optimizations, concentrate on writing good and readable and maintainable code first of all.

Comment: Unless you're on an embedded platform with software floating point, your CPU most likely stores all floating point values in registers that are double sized.

Comment: For the record, I'm looking at this question because I am on an embedded platform with hardware single precision and software double precision float.

Comment: Consider rolling your own version, or checking if your platform offers platform-specific function for this task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strtof` instead, it will return a float.

[See documentation here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/)

Comment: Question is tagged [ansi-c]. According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) `strtof`was added in C99, so you're at compilers mercy on whether that function exists. (BTW www.cplusplus.com is a poor reference for C questions)

Answer (score 0):

If the platform does have a direct "string to float" conversion routine and the compiler is optimizing, it will certainly call that conversion routine via:

```
char *buf = ...
float y; 
if (sscanf(buf, "%f", &y) == 1) Success();
```

If not, then use

```
float y = (float)atof(buf);
```

Note that the second could be optimized by the compiler to call the "string to float" if it violates the subtle [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) that otherwise occurs with this 2nd code.